# Add url options to link_to pointing to an object of unknown type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

This is probably a trivial question, but haven't found an answer yet...
I am trying to add links into my `ActionMailer`, using the `:only_path => false` option.

I am linking to an object `@event` which is of unknown type, so I can't use the old syntax `:controller => 'something', :action => :show etc.` or `event_path(@event)`

In short, this:

```
link_to 'Please RSVP', @event, :only_path => false
```

...does not work as expected, the `:only_path` option is ignored. I've tried variations of it with `{}` but to no avail.

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution in a different SO thread.

Use the `polymorphic_path` helper. Documented [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_path)

So, for the above:

```
<%= link_to 'RSVP now', polymorphic_path(@event, :only_path => false) %>
```